# Alter DB SET SERIALIZABLE ON

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level

How enable SQL Server DB SERIALIZABLE. Expecting this to happen at DB Level. I need not use everytime Transaction level.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction isolation level is specified by the client application. The default is `READ_COMMITTED` and must be explicitly changed by the app if a different level is desired. There is no (supported) way to do this at the server/database level. See [this blog post by Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ialonso/2012/11/26/how-to-set-the-default-transaction-isolation-level-server-wide/).